# Oracle XE 10 sc_core.js:472 Uncaught ReferenceError: $x is not defined

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-xe

Just installed Oracle XE10g, trying to migrate from PHPMyAdmin to oracle, and in the SQL command page, a javascript error appears and the SQL code is not running

A Snapshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaXXM.png

Answer (score 1):

This looks like 10g XE Application Express' SQL Workshop.

Anyway:

- remove single quotes, everywhere in that command
- use VARCHAR**2**, not VARCHAR datatype
- rename `date` column to something else; `date` is reserved word (for datatype)
- remove `INT` datatype's *size*

In other words, should be like this:

```
SQL> create table bags
  2    (num        int not null,
  3     id         int not null,
  4     user_id    int not null,
  5     product_id varchar2(11) not null,
  6     market_id  varchar2(11) not null,
  7     price      int not null,
  8     quantity   varchar2(255) not null,
  9     c_date     date not null);

Table created.

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks for the effort, but still it's not running, I thinks the problem is in the js code of the oracle page

Comment: You're welcome. As code I posted shows, Oracle *creates* a table if you use correct syntax. Although Apex 2.x is *very old*, 10g as well, such a CREATE TABLE statement shouldn't be a problem. It would probably work in even older database versions. Anyway, if I may ask: why did you install such an old version? Oracle offers 18cXE nowadays; consider installing that version instead. Or, at least, 11gXE which comes with Apex 4.x. Honestly, I don't remember how that early Apex' Workshop worked ... if I were you, I'd install new(er) database and SQL Developer as a GUI tool (not Apex Workshop).

Comment: I chose the smallest in size from some options,
but yeah, I guess the best thing is to download a newer version